# Question about a complex integral: $\int^{5+i \infty}_{5-i\infty} f(z)dz.$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am studying a book, and I came across with the following integral

$\int^{5+i \infty}_{5-i\infty} f(z)dz.$
I can not understand how can I handle this integral.

I was thinking to be like $$\int^{z_1}_{z_2} f(z)dz.$$
and if  $f$ be analytic, to take any path that connects the two points. But I am confused about these points. Because on $\mathbb{C}$ we have only one infinity.

Comment: $$\int_{5-i\infty }^{5+i\infty }f(z)dz:=\lim_{t\to \infty }\int_{5-it}^{5+it}f(z)dz.$$

Comment: If $f(z) =u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is not analytic and the path is the staightline contour from $5-i\infty$ to $5+i\infty$, then we can write 

$$\int_{5-i\infty}^{5+i\infty}f(z)\,dz=\int_{-\infty}^\infty (u(5,y)+iv(5,y))\,i\,dy$$

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2657644/42969.

Comment: Many Thanks to all of you!